# Quill Resize Module Error on Try to Delete Image Next Js

Tags: next.js, quill

Im using React-Quill with React-quill-resize-module for resizing the image. All functionality was fine until i want to remove image from the editor. When i press delete button on my image (try to remove the image from the editor), it resulting an error like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sioxE.png)

error message:

```
Call Stack
HTMLDocument.checkImage
node_modules\quill-image-resize-module-react\image-resize.min.js (1:15098)
```

Here's my editor component code:

```
Quill.register('modules/imageResize', ImageResize);

const modules = {
    ...,
    imageResize: {
      parchment: Quill.import('parchment'),
      modules: ['Resize', 'DisplaySize'],
    },
  };

  const formats = [
    ...
  ];
  return (
    <ReactQuill
      value={value}
      onChange={setValue}
      modules={modules}
      formats={formats}
      theme="snow"
    />
  );
```

This is how i import the editor in my page:

```
const Editor = dynamic(() => import('@app/components/editor/Editor'), {
  ssr: false,
});

...

 return <Editor {...editorProps} />
```

My assumptions was it has to be SSR problems, because when i read the quill-resize-module code, it try to access window.quill in checkImage functions. However im not sure enough about this, but im very thankful if there is any advice to resolve this error!

Answer (score 0):

Add the source code to your app, then find the code:

```
checkImage = (evt) => {
   if (this.img) {
     if (evt.keyCode == 46 || evt.keyCode == 8) {
       window.Quill.find(this.img).deleteAt(0);
     }
     this.hide();
    }
};
```

Change to

```
import Quill from "quill"
checkImage = (evt) => {
   if (this.img) {
     if (evt.keyCode == 46 || evt.keyCode == 8) {
       Quill.find(this.img).deleteAt(0);
     }
     this.hide();
    }
};
```